# Загрузка (зеркалирование) на несколько FTP-серверов

Tags: ftp, ftp-сервер, зеркало

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следующую задачу:
Есть сервер на WIN, на него должны закачиваться файлы по ФТП. Каким образом можно организовать зеркалирование загруженного файла еще на три-четыре фтп-сервера?
Идеально, если в режиме реального времени, но можно и с какой-то периодичностью. Если ли уже готовое решение для подобных ситуаций? Гугление приводит только к решениям типа синхронизации локальной папки с папкой на фтп, мне же нужна именно выгрузка полученного файла на три-четыре других ФТП.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell

по ссылке есть разные варианты выгрузки на фтп используя скрипты на powershell. Там же через powershell можно сделать регулярный запуск скрипта.

Или чуть сложнее вариант - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/35119e57-893a-4981-909c-238d5175f33b/best-way-to-run-powershell-script-when-file-is-added-to-a-specific-directory?forum=winserverpowershell
запуск скриптов при изменении в нужном каталоге.